# Vectorizing conditional summing loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, conditional-statements, vectorization

I have two M by N matrices, labeled A and B, and I would like to create a vector containing the sum of all items in B for each unique value of A. For example I have the following matrices:

```
A = [6 2 3 4
     5 2 3 3
     5 5 6 2];

B = [.2 .5 .4 .1
     .7 .2 .5 .1
     .6 .6 .1 .9];
```

and I would like to create a vector C where each index corresponds to the index of `D = unique(A)`. So for this case, `D = [2,3,4,5,6]` and

```
for I = 1:length(D)
    C(I) = sum(B(A(:)==D(I));
end
```

This gets really slow when D is 2000 items long and A and B both are ~4000x20 matrices. Any help on speeding this up? I tried doing the following:

```
Indxs = bsxfun(@eq,A,reshape(D,1,1,length(D)));
for I = 1:size(Indxs,3)
    C(I) = sum(B(Indxs(:,:,I));
end
```

but it's not really any faster.

Comment: Also, I am preallocating C to speed it up that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the usual combination of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[D, ~, uA] = unique(A(:));
C = accumarray(uA, B(:));
```

With your example data, the result is:

```
>> D
D =
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6

>> C
C =
    1.6000
    1.0000
    0.1000
    1.9000
    0.3000
```

What `accumarray` does, in its most basic form (two input arguments), is to sum all second-argument values that have the same first-argument value.

---

If `A` contains only positive integers, there's a one-line solution with [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and [`find`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
[D, ~, C] = find(sparse(A(:), 1, B(:)));
```

This works because `sparse` accumulates values corresponding to the same index.

Comment: +1 Could you explain what accumarray does a little bit clearer than on the MatLab help file?

Comment: That was much faster! I didn't know about accumarray, thanks!

Comment: @EJG89 I have added an explanation. I also include a second solution using `sparse`